# Reloading Data error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Here the code is for refreshing the data in collection View]

I used this code to refresh data in the collection view, where this error came up. is there any alternative method?

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand, one would general start variable names with a lowercase letter (e.g. `collectionView` rather than `CollectionView`). Also, you repeatedly post questions with image snapshots showing error messages. Don't do that (or if you do, also include the text of the error message in your question, too). The purpose of Stack Overflow is to be a searchable repository of questions and answers, and the way your question was composed, there's no way anyone could ever find this question on the basis of the text of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

This `CollectionView` variable is likely an implicitly unwrapped optional that is actually `nil`. Add a check to see if it is nil.

In terms of why it's `nil`, it's impossible to say on the basis of the information provided. Perhaps it's an `IBOutlet` that was never hooked up properly. Maybe the whole view controller was instantiated incorrectly (e.g. you manually instantiated the view controller rather than calling the storyboard's `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`). If you're unable to determine why the collection view was `nil`, you have to show us how the collection view was instantiated (and if it's an `IBOutlet`, how the entire view controller was instantiated).